# How do I add a stroke (border) only on the top of a shape layer in photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, website-design, button

I am trying to create a button for my website using Photoshop's rectangle shape tool. I want to add a border only on top of the button. How will get that effect?

Comment: Sorry? I'm not sure I understand. If you'd like to add a stroke, add a stroke.

Comment: @Johannes sorry  i need to add stroke for a rectangle box  i need it only for top of a rectangle!

Comment: It's still not clear to me what the problem is. If you add a screenshot, we may be able to help.

Comment: You can not stroke one side of a rectangle. If you need one stroke, use the line tool, not the rectangle tool.

Comment: You can emulate a single-sided stroke with a drop shadow. For example to [achieve this](http://i.imgur.com/AjOTFWS.png) use [these settings](http://i.imgur.com/JRMHMi9.png)